# Get content of Dynlist attribute with Spring ldapTemplate

Tags: java, spring, openldap, spring-ldap

I have some issues with the memberURL attribute of Dynlist in OpenLDAP.

I have an attribute memberURL of the form :

```
memberURL : ldap:///<BASE>?mail?one?(uid=<USER-UID>)
```

This works with a classic ldapsearch.

But once in Spring I don't see any way to get it back via my request:

```
ldapTemplate.findOne(query, Example.class);
```

or via the ldapTemplate.find or ldapTemplate.findAll methods.

In my Example class I specified the memberURL this way:

```
@Attribute(name = "memberURL")
private String memberURL;
```

I guess this attribute is not essential in the request but when I remove it, it doesn't work either.
I also specified the attribute I wish to receive :

```
@Attribute(name = "mail")
private String mail;
```

But when retrieving the ldap info, the mail attribute remains empty and the memberURL attribute contains the memberURL.

```
"mail": null,
...
"memberURL": "ldap:///<BASE>?mail?one?(uid=<USER-ID>)",
```

When I copy the request made by Spring in LDAP and I reproduce it with ldapsearch, LDAP returns the mail to me.
So I think that Spring can't assign this mail value to my class attribute.